# Drum show off center with cylinder

Tags: brakes, noise

My 1998 Honda Civic Ex driver's side rear drum brakes make a "click click click" noise at low speeds only when brakes are applied.

All new hardware, shoes, and drums. Only thing not replaced are the backing plates.

Noticed when looking for anything that could be causing it that the shoe doesn't sit centered like the others. I can push it down but soon as brakes are applied it goes off center again (mating point slightly higher on the cylinder than the other shoes)

Any ideas why? I'm guessing this is causing the click noise as I don't see anything else it could be [image]

Comment: How loose were the shoes when you took the drum off? Did it come right off, or did you have to turn the adjuster off to loosen them up? My thinking is the shoes just need adjusting to take up excess slack. The slacks allowing the shoes to move more than they should when the brakes are applied.

Comment: I've tried adjusting numerous times actually and at one point purposely made them tighter than they should be and the clicking actually got louder

Comment: Does it make the same noise when braking in reverse?

Comment: Never noticed it in reverse

Comment: What is the make/model/year of the vehicle?

Comment: 98 Honda Civic ex. Should have included that. I'll edit it in now

Comment: I wonder if the stand offs on the backing plate wore down to a point where the retaining springs can't give enough tension holding the shoes to the backing plate?

Comment: Should be relatively easy to compare the stand offs on the other side and see if there is much difference.

Comment: Couldn't tell much of a difference. But I only peaked behind the shoes. However I had a smaller retaining pin that holds shoe against backing plate. Tried that and it gave more tension. Clicking has stopped but brakes make a creaking noise when ebrake is used

Comment: Check the backing plate for abnormal wear where the shoes contact the plate, there should be 3 contact points for each shoe. These contact points need to be cleaned and lubricated with a bit of grease when doing a brake job but is often skipped by mechanics causing grooves to be worn into the backing plate and also cause noise when the shoes are applied by the wheel cylinder.., this may be your problem, if so repair or replace tha backing plates. http://www.handymanlyness.com/archives/auto/repair/brakes/Dodge/Dakota_2wd/rear/mxbrrd26aro_brake_shoes_96_Dakota.jpg

Comment: Thanks @Moab I lightly sanded and added anti-seize paste on these 3 points but at the time I didn't think to check the evenness of them. This was the first time the rear brakes had been replaced since the car was new.

Comment: Contact points on the backing plate should be smooth and flat.

Comment: Would it make sense one side wore down more than the other causing the shoe to need more tension?

Answer (score 1):

A warped drum could make a clicking noise but if started when you changed parts it seems like that's what started it.  If you haven't done too many miles on the shoes you could try moving them around and seeing if the problem follows the shoe.